# How to bind height in RectJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to bind height of two blocks;

```
    const [blockHeight, setBlockHeight] = useState(0);
    const inputCommandsRef = useRef(null);    

    useEffect(() => {
     setBlockHeight(inputCommandsRef.current?.clientHeight)
    }, [inputCommandsRef])
    
    <div className="row" ref={inputCommandsRef}>
     <div style={{padding: '20px'}} className="col-xxl-9">
      <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>
        
     <div className="flex-line d-flex justify-content-start col-xxl-3" 
          style={{ maxHeight: `${maxHeight}px` }}>
      <h1>maxHeight ${maxHeight}</h1>
      <table>
        ....
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Problem that when  I change size of `textArea` the height of second block is not change (and value in h1 tag also), I just get once height and that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `useRef` variables inside `depsArray`, they work in different way. You just need a [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

```
function Block() {
  const [blockSize, setBlockSize] = useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  });
  const inputCommandsRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { current } = inputCommandsRef;
    if (!current) return;

    const setSizes = () => {
      setBlockSize({
        width: current.clientWidth,
        height: current.clientHeight
      });
    };
    setSizes();

    const obs = new ResizeObserver(setSizes);
    obs.observe(current);

    return () => {
      obs.unobserve(current);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="row" ref={inputCommandsRef}>
      <div style={{ padding: "20px" }} className="col-xxl-9">
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div
        className="flex-line d-flex justify-content-start col-xxl-3"
        style={{ maxHeight: `${blockSize.height}px` }}
      >
        <h1>maxHeight ${blockSize.height}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit silly-chandrasekhar-6h2i0x]